# Use js to change input<type="datetime-local"> value

Tags: javascript, datetime

```js
var time = new Date("2018-03-15T20:30");
time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 60);
document.getElementById("myInput").valueAsNumber = time.getTime();
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="myInput">
```

It's my code, I expect the input will display 2018-03-15T21:30, but in some computers(not all computers), it will display 2018-03-15T13:30. It seems like timezone problem. How to solve it?

Comment: What timezone are you in and what timezone are the computers in that see this issue? I'm guessing they are UTC-8 so maybe Alaska

Comment: I'm in Taiwan, our timezone is GMT+8.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the timezone using `getTimezoneOffset()`, as follows:

```js
var time = new Date("2018-03-15T20:30");
console.log(time.getTime() + " | " + time.toUTCString());

time = new Date(time - time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
console.log('After correcting timezone:')
console.log(time.getTime() + " | " + time.toUTCString());

time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 60);
console.log('After adding 60 minutes:')
console.log(time.getTime() + " | " + time.toUTCString());
```

Console output for me, I am in GMT+1 timezone with Daylight Saving not active:

```
1521142200000 | Thu, 15 Mar 2018 19:30:00 GMT
After correcting timezone:
1521145800000 | Thu, 15 Mar 2018 20:30:00 GMT
After adding 60 minutes:
1521149400000 | Thu, 15 Mar 2018 21:30:00 GMT
```

Note that `toUTCString()` always prints GMT, regardless of 'what we know' that the time variable contains. I use it to clearly show the content of the variable.